# Does the isomorphism preserve Galois?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a subtle question.

Let k, K, L be fields and suppose $k\subset K\subset L$.  Let L/K, K/k be Galois, and let $\sigma$ be k-embedding of L.

Then, is $\sigma L/ \sigma K$ Galois?

I first want to show that $\sigma K$-embedding of $\sigma L$ preserves $\sigma L$. But I can't;(  Please help!

Comment: Do you mean that $\sigma$ is a $k$-embedding of $L$ into a fixed algebraic closure of $L$?

Comment: of course! More precisely, this is an algebraic closure of $\sigma L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial $f(x) \in K[x]$, then by applying $\sigma$ to the coefficients of $f(x)$, you can show that $\sigma L$ is the splitting field of $\sigma f(x)$ over $\sigma K$, which is still separable, because if $r_1,\dots,r_n$ are the distinct roots of $f$, then $$\sigma f(x) = \sigma((x-r_1)\dots(x-r_n)) = (x-\sigma(r_1))\dots(x-\sigma(r_n)),$$ and since $\sigma$ is injective, the new roots are all distinct in $\sigma L$.

Then if $\sigma K \subseteq F \subseteq \sigma L$ is an intermediate field extension containing all of the roots of $\sigma f$, then the inverse image $\sigma^{-1}(F) \subseteq L$ contains the roots of $f$, and thus contains $L$, so $\sigma^{-1}(F) = L$, so $F = \sigma L$; conversely $\sigma L$ contains all the roots of $\sigma f$, so it's the splitting field.

This all relies on the fact that $\sigma f$ has coefficients in $\sigma K$, which is clear, since $f$ has coefficients in $K$.